# Confused about sizeof with structures and unions

Tags: c, sizeof

Question from somewhere asked to label the size of this structure's parts and I am not sure how to tell the size by initializing it. Any explanation on the answer will be helpful.
The system is 32-bit if that helps.

- `sizeof( struct Artist_A )`?
- `sizeof( artist_record )`?
- `sizeof( artist_record[1].record )`?
- `sizeof( artist_record[1].group )`?

  ```
  struct Artist_A {
     short group;
     char title[20];
     union Rec{
        void * ptr;
        int num;
        char character;
        double real;
    } record;
   };

  struct Artist_A artist_record[200];
  ```

Comment: You can try it out, if the result is not what you expected, then ask.

Comment: Are unions arbitrary sizes?

Comment: Official wording is like "size of the union shall be big enough to contain largest data member", in you case it is double, with size 8. But that is minimum size of the union, it could be larger

Comment: There are no specific numerical answers for your questions. It is highly implementation-dependent. It depends on the actual sizes of the fundamental types. It depends on the alignment-related behavior of your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result you get on a GCC compiler for this code,

```
truct Artist_A {
   short group;
   char title[20];
   union Rec{
      void * ptr;
      int num;
      char character;
      double real;
  } record;
 };

struct Artist_A artist_record[200];
int main(){
    /* %zu is used as sizeof() returns std::size_t */
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof( struct Artist_A )); 
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof( artist_record ));
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof( artist_record[1].record )); 
    printf("%zu\n",sizeof( artist_record[1].group )); 
}
```

Output:

```
32 
6400 
8 
2
```

These are some bytes required!

Explaination:

`struct Artist_A`:

- `short group`: 4 for the short, even though short requires only 2 bytes `Data structure alignment` is done! Data alignment means putting the data at a memory offset equal to some multiple of the word size. In 32bit systems word size would be 4bytes (while in x64 it would be 8bytes).This actually increases performance.
- `char title[20]`:20 bytes are taken, that is one byte for char into 20 elements.
- `uinion record` : As per the official documentation, *The union is only as big as necessary to hold its largest data member*. So it adds another 8 bytes.

Comment: Minor: Better to use matching printf specifier `"%zu"` with results of `sizeof()` which is type `size_t`: `printf("%zu\n",sizeof( struct Artist_A ));`  `"%d"` will not always work.

Comment: Quick question before though, Is this on a 32 bit machine? Because the short group says its 2 bytes in the last printf. That contradicts the sum of the struct which is 32( title(20 bytes)+ record(8 bytes) + group(4 bytes) = 32. Not really the scope of the question I had, which was how how to sum up the size of the structure in a 32-bit system.

Comment: I think I made it clear on my explanation: This is a 32bit system! unless, after having the data alignment padding `short group` would have taken the size of 8bytes (i.e in x64). Got it?

Comment: in my structure has only one short variable then I print that size of the structure that time it printed 2 only why it will print only two please explain

Comment: @Dinal24 - I don't know how the short will take 4 bytes, please explain me clearly. i create a structure as shown. it will print two only.. i don't know how its take                                       struct hello{
short a;
};
printf("sizeof short=%d\n",sizeof(struct hello));

Comment: @Rajalakshmi & Bhuvanesh I think this link will help you to understand what happens here! :)
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory allocated to a union will be large enough to hold the largest member of the union. In your example on a 32-bit system you would have the size of 32 bytes. It is broken down as follows:

- 4 bytes for the short (2 bytes, plus 2 additional bytes for alignment)
- 20 bytes for the char array
- 8 bytes for the largest type in the union (double)

That is confirmed by `sizeof(Artist_A)` on i686 Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: Alignment in the struct, not record[1].group?

Answer (score 0):

A union is *at least* the size of its largest member; it may be larger to satisfy any alignment requirements (for example, if the largest member of the union is a 17-element array of `char`, but the system requires 4-byte alignment, then the size of the union may be padded to 20 bytes.

Similarly, there may be padding between members of a struct, also to satisfy alignment requirements; thus, the size reported by `sizeof` may be larger than the sum of the sizes of the individual members.

Thus, `union Rec` is at least as large as the `real` member, which on a 32-bit system is most likely 8 bytes.  So `struct Artist_A` is at least 8 + 20 + `sizeof (short)`, which is at least 2; assuming it is, that's 30 bytes, probably with 2 additional bytes of padding to bring it to 32 bytes total.